# Bash regular expression question

Tags: bash, regex

I am using

```
ps -ef | grep java | wc -l
```

to find the number of java processes running at any given time.

The above command obviously counts the "ps -ef | grep java" command also in the result.

To avoid this, I found out that I could use

```
ps -ef | grep [j]ava | wc -l
```

and it works fine. However, I would like to figure out the reason why it is able to skip the original command from the results.

Comment: By the way. try running 'ps -ef | grep -c [j]ava'

Answer (score 10):

Because when you grep for [j]ava, the process is named 'grep [j]ava'. '[j]ava' doesn't match the regex '[j]ava', and thus doesn't show up in the results.

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
ps -ef | grep [j]ava | wc -l
```

you are using the pattern `[j]ava` which matches any single character between the square brackets (which consists only of the single letter `j`) followed immediately by the characters `ava`.  The grep process itself does not contain the letter `j` followed immediately by the letters `ava`, but instead contains a square bracket, then `j`, then a closing square bracket, then `ava`.

That is, the pattern does not match itself.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly an answer to your question, but...

Another common way to accomplish the same thing is:

```
ps -ef|grep java|grep -v grep|wc -l
```

This of course works by doing an inverted grep on the term grep itself

Answer (score 1):

You've changed the name of the grep process, so that it no longer contains the term "java"

Answer (score 1):

To go along with other answers to hopefully help clarify:

grep java matches anything that has java within it.

> grep **java**
>   **java**

grep [j]ava matches explicitly "java":

> grep [j]ava <- There is no string "java" here so it does not match
>   **java**

Answer (score 1):

use the pgrep command?

Comment: I think the pgrep command is not universal across all unix platforms

Comment: I know from experience it works on solaris and linux.
Don't know about BSDs or other proprietary unices.

Answer (score 0):

starting with JDK 1.5, you have the jps  (linux /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/jps). You can use it on all the operating system (linux, windows, solaris)